# How to return a string from a MACRO function in C?

Tags: c, string, macros, c-preprocessor

I want to create a string based on the value passed as argument to the MACRO FUNCTION.
Something Like:

```
#define ABC(x,y) return "anystr_x_y.tar.bz2"
main()
{
   a = ABC(2,3);
}
```

So Finally, It should return "anystr_2_3.tar.bz2"

I was wondering how to create that string with the value passed as argument to MACRO fnc.

Any help !
thanks !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Define your macro like this, using the "stringize operator":

```
#define ABC(x,y) "anystr_" #x "_" #y ".tar.bz2"
```

Comment: I though it was ## for token concat. Or is #x not concat but something else?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `#` is stringize. On my compiler the concatenation is done automatically (no need for `##`). I thought it was standard ?

Comment: Thank you. I've just learnt something. I'm sure it is standard, I asked the question out of ignorance on my part!

Comment: It's because strings are a special case, they are always automatically concatenated. When you write `x = "ABC" "DEF";` it is the same thing as writing `x = "ABCDEF";`

Comment: Thanks! I was using ## operator instead of #.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan To be honest my preprocessor knowledge is kind of shaky so I wasn't sure either.

Answer (score 1):

Macros don't return stuff, since they are not functions. They are merely token replacement functionality. What you actually want is a though one, and in your place I would do it with a function instead. However, a solution could look like:

```
#define ABC(x,y) "anystr_" #x "_" #y ".tar.bz2"
```

This takes leverage from the fact that string literals are collapsed togheter, so `"Hello " "World!"` is interpreted as `"Hello World!"`.

Comment: @cnicutar: The Boost Preprocessor library is based in the preprocessor, which is shared between C and C++.

Comment: Correct, however, why using boost stringize, when plain standard stringize would do? "anystr_" #x "_" #y ".tar.bz2"

Comment: I didn't know about the Boost preprocessor library and didn't know it works for C :-)

Comment: @Suma: Because I wasn't aware of such functionality. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a macro function in C (nor C++). Macros are processed by the preprocessor, before the code is compiled. Your example code above will be processed by the compiler to this:

```
main()
{
  a = return "anystr_x_y.tar.bz2"
}
```

To achieve what you are trying to do, you need to tell the preprocessor to concattenate x, y and the constant parts of your string. You do that using the ## operator, e.g.:

```
#define ABC(x,y) ("anystr_" ## x ## "_" ## y ## ".tar.bz2")
```

That will result in the following code being passed to the compiler:

```
main()
{
  a = ("anystr_2_3.tar.bz2")
}
```

Comment: That would result in an error unless `x` and `y` are specified as `"2"` and `"3"`.

Comment: Yes, this is probably the most one can get from a macro. Othen the concatenation there is almost nothing you can do in preprocessor. However, you goo concat wrong, you need to use stringize instead, concatenation is done automatically on strings:("anystr_" #x "_" #y ".tar.bz2")

Comment: `##` is the token pasting operator... not stringizing.  It should be using the single `#` on the parameter.

Comment: @e8johan: Thank you very much for your valuable briefing. 
Thats what i was looking for !